# Unknown AirTag near me?

Tags: ios, geolocation, airtag

I recently got a message on my iPad that an unknown AirTag is moving with me. By the time I noticed the notification I was unable to play a sound or locate the current location of the AirTag. The map shows a red airline to a house in a city about 560 km away from me. I did not stay there. I searched my stuff and used a Bluetooth scanner but could not find anything.

I can't decide if this alert should be taken seriously or is it some kind of a glitch.

Does anyone know of a way to track down the AirTag in question?

Answer (score 3):

This [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212227) page has a wealth of AirTag info. I'm glad I found it, as it answers some questions I had myself.

As for your question, here's a possible answer lifted from the Apple Support page linked above.

---

### Find the unknown AirTag, AirPods, or Find My network accessory

If you get an alert that an AirTag, AirPods, or another Find My network accessory is traveling with you, follow these steps to find it.
First, check on the Find My app if you're able to play a sound on the unknown accessory:

1. Tap the alert.
2. Tap Continue and then tap Play Sound.
3. Listen for the sound. You can play it again if you need more time to find the item.

If the option to play a sound isn't available, the item might not be with you anymore. Or if it was with you overnight, its identifier might have changed. Find My uses the identifier to determine that it's the same item moving with you. If the item is within range of its owner, you also won't be able to play a sound.

If the unknown accessory is an AirTag and you have a supported [iPhone model with Ultra Wideband](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212274), you can also tap Find Nearby to use Precision Finding to help you locate the unknown AirTag.

1. Tap the alert.
2. Tap Continue, then tap Find Nearby.
3. Follow the onscreen instructions and move around the space until your iPhone connects to the unknown AirTag.
4. Your iPhone displays the distance and direction to the unknown AirTag. Use that information to get closer to the unknown AirTag until you find it

• When the AirTag is within Bluetooth range of your iPhone, you can play a sound on the AirTag by tapping the **Play Sound** button

• If your iPhone says that more light is required, tap the **Turn Flashlight On** button

5. When you're done, tap the Done button

If the option to play a sound isn't available or you're unable to hear the sound, or if you can't locate the item with Precision Finding, and you believe the item is still with you, look through your belongings to try to find it. Check on your person, or in anything in your possession that could contain this device. It could be in an item that you don’t check often, like a jacket pocket, the outer compartment of a bag, or your vehicle. If you can't find the device and if you feel your safety is at risk, go to a safe public location and contact law enforcement.